# How to define default values for snippet placeholders?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

When creating snippets I would like to know if it is possible to define a default value for a placeholder if no value is assigned.

For example, having this php snippet:

```
{
  "get_list": {
        "prefix": "get_list",
        "body": "$${1:beanList} = $${2:bean}->get_list('${3:order_by}', \"${4:where}\", ${5:row_offset}, ${6:limit}, ${7:max}, ${8:show_deleted});",
        "description": "Get a paginate bean list"
    },
}
```

Where placeholders from tabstops 5 to 8 have the following default values:

```
$row_offset = 0
$limit= -1
$max= -1
$show_deleted = 0
```

I tried with choices in the following way, but with no success:

```
{
  "get_list": {
        "prefix": "get_list",
        "body": "$${1:beanList} = $${2:bean}->get_list('${3:order_by}', \"${4:where}\", ${5:row_offset|0|}, ${6:limit}, ${7:max}, ${8:show_deleted});",
        "description": "Get a paginate bean list"
    },
}
```

Please take a look to the `row_offset` definition. When the snippet is rendered I get the following

```
$beanList = $bean->get_list('order_by', "where", row_offset|0|, limit, max, show_deleted);
```

In this scenario what I would like to happen is in case I omit a placeholder value `0` is assigned.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest you will get to what you want are "choices".  See [snippet choices](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_choice).

Your terminology is a little off.  In `${6:limit}` for example - that entire thing is the placeholder and `limit` is the default value for it.  So it already has a default value - `limit` - and now you want to have another.  So try this syntax:

```
${6:|limit,-1|}
```

> Placeholders can have choices as values. The syntax is a comma
>   separated enumeration of values, enclosed with the pipe-character, for
>   example ${1|one,two,three|}. When the snippet is inserted and the
>   placeholder selected, choices will prompt the user to pick one of the
>   values.

Comment: You are right `choices` looks like the the closest solution at the moment. `${6|limit,-1|}` do the trick, Thanks Mark for answering